# brew update command failed on macos monterey

Tags: homebrew

I have a problem while updating homebrew. The error messages says,
Cask 'google-backup-and-sync' definition is invalid: invalid 'depends_on macos' value: unknown or unsupported macOS version: :mavericks. How to solve this problem? plz help.

Comment: Can you run `brew config`  for me?